# Which (if any) space telescope would have worked longer if it hadn't simply run out of helium?

Tags: observational-astronomy, space-telescope, infrared

In [this answer to *Why is the hot part of Webb's MIRI cryocooler in the 300K area?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/60209/12102) and comments below discusses the helium refrigerator used for cooling JWST's [Mid-Infrared Instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIRI_(Mid-Infrared_Instrument)) or MIRI.

A [comment there](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/60202/why-is-the-hot-part-of-webbs-miri-cryocooler-in-the-300k-area#comment199277_60209) talks about the disadvantages of using a dewar or reservoir of helium that performed passive cooling by a slow boil-off. Advantages are that it doesn't fail like a compressor would nor does it vibrate (though it can slosh). Disadvantage is that it runs out, which might come a lot sooner than a(n extremely well-designed) compressor failure would.

> ...what the 'dewar flask' cooling is... a flask of liquid helium provides liquid helium to locations needing cooling where the liquid absorbs heat, turns to gas which is then vented to space. Long service life would mean a very large, very heavy amount of helium. It would also mean an absolute hard limit to useable lifetime.

That "hard limit" sounds familiar, though I think the limit was softened by limited operation at shorter wavelengths. In any event, I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Which (if any) space telescope would have worked longer if it hadn't simply run out of helium?

Answer (score 20):

Past infrared telescopes ([IRAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRAS), [Spitzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spitzer_Space_Telescope), others I can't remember) in space have generally used expendable liquid He. They either ceased operation or lost a large part of their capability when the He ran out.

Also there were failures caused by design errors in the difficult-to-test cryogenic systems. [WIRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_Field_Infrared_Explorer) lost its cryogen store (hydrogen, not He) when its aperture cover came off prematurely. The x-ray quantum calorimeter on [Suzaku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suzaku_(satellite)) lost its He due to a thermal runaway caused by inadequate venting.

Comment: Yes, Spitzer and specifically the "[Spitzer Warm Mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spitzer_Space_Telescope#Warm_mission_and_end_of_mission)" is what I was trying to remember, thanks!

Answer (score 18):

The [Herschel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herschel_Space_Observatory) infrared telescope is another recent telescope that stopped working once it ran out of Helium for its coolant.